# Need help to understand some definitions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

I found following two definitions in a  Ben Israel's book whose title is 
Generalized inverses: Theory and applications:

For any $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, define

$R (A, B) = \{Y = A X B \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}: X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m} \}$

and

$N (A, B) = \{X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m} : A X B = 0 \}$

which we shall call the range and null space of $(A, B)$, respectively.
I am confused with this definition. In what context we are calling this range and null spaces of (A, B)? Is there any reference that might help me?

Could any body  help me to understand this definition?

thanks

Comment: $X \mapsto AXB$ is a linear transformation, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like the superoperator formalism. Think of your product matrices as vectors, then the following holds:
$$
\text{vec}(AXB) = (B^T \otimes A) \text{vec}(X).
$$
(see [here](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~jdaunize/docs/Kronecker.pdf) for a definition of $\text{vec}(X)\;$ and here for more information: [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations))